# xen to kvm migration

Tags: xen, migration, kvm-virtualization

i've just migrated some xen vms to kvm. so far everything is working fine.

except for one little thing: when i start virtual-manager and looking at the vm's display, there is no `login:` prompt.

i see, the boot output and everything starts up fine...

i think init, might be pointing to a wrong display.

thanks a lot for any reply...

BTW: i did the migration of the ubuntu hardy vms by hand (followed [this tutorial](http://blog.pregos.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/XEN-to-KVM-Migration.pdf) that google returned me). worked like a charm, except for the login prompt on the host's screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your image's `/etc/inittab` and see if the getty lines are using real tty and not referencing `hvc0` or another xen specific device.

Comment: there is no /etc/inittab in my ubuntu. and a `grep -iR hvc0 /etc` doesn't give me any results...

Comment: problem still exists, but thanks for answering :-)

Answer (score 0):

how did you perform the migration? virt-v2v should have set things up for you.

In any case, booting with a liveCD iso should give you access to fix whatever boot issues you may have

Comment: hi, i cannot find virt-v2v on my host ubuntu  10.04 LTS. i did the migration of the ubuntu hardy vms by hand (followed some tutorial that google returned me). worked like a charm, except for the login prompt on the host's screen. thanks a lot in advance for any help on this.

Comment: I have virt-v2v in Fedora